# how to include AntiForgeryToken in an ajax action link in mvc?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, security, razor, csrf

I have the following code:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", 
new { id = item.ID, RequestVerificationToken=*What comes here?*}, 
new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "formsIndex" })
```

I want to add the verification token to the link without using javascript in client side, it seems like a redundant dependancy since i already own that value in server. Is there a proper way to do that?

Comment: Create a form (`Ajax.BeginForm()`) and include `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.antiforgerytoken%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) (my emphasis)

> HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken Method
>
> Generates a hidden form field (anti-forgery token) that is validated when the **form** is submitted.

You need a form element to generate the anti-forgery token.

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", new { id = item.ID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "formsIndex" }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> // style to look like a link if that's what you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works as expected, altough I was hoping for a pretier solution. When creating the AntiForgeryToken hiddin field the view engine accesses the token value, it seems like there should be a way to access it without the input element wrapped around it

Comment: Eventually I've parsed the input element and extracted the token, only to realize that there is no way to post a message, which means the only way to pass data with action link, regardless if its get or post, is with url parameters, which doesnt work with AntiForgeryToken. that means there is no pretier alternative.