# MVC Ajax.Actionlink Failure response returns text of jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, actionlink

So I have a simple AJAX.Actionlink that's acting weird. I have all the appropriate js libraries (unobtrusive, etc). In fact, previously in my project for a different view I used this AJAX.Actionlink and it works with success. But for some reason on this one view, I'm getting the OnFailure event to trigger.... which is fine if I can get the error message from it so I know why it failed, but the response's ERROR property is actually returning a function from my jquery file.

Here is my actionlink

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" - Delete Ajax", "Delete", new { @id = item.id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnFailure = "OnFailure", OnSuccess = "OnSuccessDelete" })
```

I have a break point set in my controller for my "Delete" action which was triggered just fine before when I did a normal, non-ajax post on it, passing the same ID.  But now it's not getting hit. The OnFailure JS function *IS* getting fired, though. Here is the function:

```
                function OnFailure(result) {
                    if (result.error) {
                        alert(result.error);
                    } else {
                        alert('no msg');
                    }
                }
```

I was hoping the error property would show something relevant to help me figure out why this wasn't posting. But the text returned is this code which is in my jquery=1.10.2.js file:

```
function() {
            if ( list ) {
                // First, we save the current length
                var start = list.length;
                (function add( args ) {
                    jQuery.each( args, function( _, arg ) {
                        var type = jQuery.type( arg );
                        if ( type === "function" ) {
                            if ( !options.unique || !self.has( arg ) ) {
                                list.push( arg );
                            }
                        } else if ( arg && arg.length && type !== "string" ) {
                            // Inspect recursively
                            add( arg );
                        }
                    });
                })( arguments );
                // Do we need to add the callbacks to the
                // current firing batch?
                if ( firing ) {
                    firingLength = list.length;
                // With memory, if we're not firing then
                // we should call right away
                } else if ( memory ) {
                    firingStart = start;
                    fire( memory );
                }
            }
            return this;
        }
```

LOLWTF?: Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It turns out that the breakpoint DOES get hit if I remove the         ValidateAntiForgeryToken check from the line above the controller action. However this then brings up a new issue.... With AJAX.ActionLink's ... is there a way to have it validate a token from the page that posted it?

Comment: Doesn't looks like this is possible (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727420/how-to-include-antiforgerytoken-in-an-ajax-action-link-in-mvc). You have to use Ajax.Beginform unless you want to create a total, messy hack